# Seam - @In Identity identity not injecting & throws nullpointer exception

Tags: servlets, jboss, seam, nullpointerexception

I am using Seam 2.0 and I have an instance variable inside my bean as

```
@In Identity identity
```

and when I use `identity.getUserName()` it throws `NullPointerException`. Can anyone tell me please what I am missing here additionally?

---

**Update**: I have defined bean instance variable as below:

```
@In Identity identity;
```

Then in my bean constructor I simply added below line to welcome the user -

```
System.out.println("Welcome - " +identity.getUsername());
```

I see below error on my Jboss console :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.lntebg.quality.QualityInspectionPlan.<init>(QualityInspectionPlan.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.instantiateJavaBean(Component.java:1315)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.instantiate(Component.java:1271)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.newInstance(Component.java:1973)
    ... 279 more
```

Comment: would you please attach the full stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas:

- Are you injecting Identity inside a Seam component?
- Seam cannot inject inside the constructor.
- Do you have these snippets in your components.xml?

`<core:init security-enabled="true" />`

and

`<security:identity />`

Answer (score 1):

Seam doesn't inject the variables until after the constructor has been called, and as such the Seam injected property is null within the constructor - hence the NPE.

Instead of referencing the Seam injected property within the constructor, create a new method such as init() and annotate it with the @Create annotation.  This method will then be automatically called after the object has been instantiated and the Seam injected properties have been set.

Hope this helps,

Chris